# DataTables Dropdown Menu that pulls multiple columns from MySQL Database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatables

I was wondering if it is possible for me to add a dropdown into the Associated Floor Plans section of the table. In this dropdown I'd like to add other URL's that are stored in the database. Would I be creating a new column in the database to call the additional URL's that are stored in Google Drive and how would I go about creating a dropdown showing all the files associated with that floor.

It's an extremely particular question seeing as it would be calling additional items from the database into what in essence is the same column.

Thank you for your instance. Also, feel free to critique the methods I've used in my code.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
if(!$con){
die("Error: ".mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("Test_Data", $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Test_DataSet");
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST TABLE</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/hmtl; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="DataTables-1.10.1/media/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="DataTables-1.10.1/media/js/jquery.DataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>


<style type="text/css">
    @import "DataTables-1.10.1/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css";
</style>
<style type="text/css">
@import "DataTables-1.10.1/examples/resources/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css";
</style>


<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#datatables').dataTable();
    })
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });
</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".various").fancybox({
            maxWidth    : 1600,
            maxHeight   : 1200,
            fitToView   : true,
            width       : '100%',
            height      : '100%',
            autoSize    : true,
            closeClick  : false,
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none'
        });
});
</script>


<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $('a.modalGeneric').fancybox({
            type: 'iframe',
            fitToView: true,
            autoSize: true,
            openEffect: 'fade',
            openSpeed: 'slow'
        });
});
</script>
<style> iframe{border: none; width: 20}</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
     <table id="datatables" class="hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
         <thead>
             <tr>
                <th>Building</th>            
                <th>Floor</th>
                <th>Number of AP</th>
                <th>Associated Floor Plans</th>
                <th>View on WebPage</th>
             </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <?php
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            ?>
            <tr class ="odd gradeX">
                <td><?php echo $row['Building']; ?></td>             
                <td><?php echo $row['Floor']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Number_Of_AP']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo '<a class="various fancybox.iframe”  href="'.$row['Associated_Floor_Plans'].'" target="_blank">'.$row['Associated_Floor_Plans'].'</a>';?></td>
                <td><?php echo '<a class="various fancybox.iframe” href="'.$row['View_On_Webpage'].'" target="_blank">View in AMP<'.$row['View_On_Webpage'].'</a>';?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
            }
        ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: "Would I be creating a new column in the `database` to call the additional URL's that are stored in Google Drive[...]" it is very hard to understand this part, did you mean new column in `datatables`? the dropdown you must create a `select` element, it is rather unclear what the issues you're having

Comment: I apologize for miswording it's kind of hard to explain. What I mean is I want to add a drop down menu to the table element called "Associated_Floor_Plans" due to the fact that there may be instances where multiple floor plans are associated with one row in the datatable. What I want to do is add a drop down that gives the option to select other floor plans. These floor plans are stored in google drive as URL's. The functionality I'm trying to add is simply to have multiple attributes from the database be stored under one row in a drop down.

Comment: Hi, I would like to know if you were able to solve this challenge as I have a similar problem but I am using an ajaxsourced file. Thanks.